# push() into deep array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, javascript-objects

Trying to push in new nested objects.  Keep getting `cannot read property push of undefined` on line 3.

Why isn't this working?  Should I be doing this another way?

```
$scope.item.deliverables[0].steps[0].versions = [];
$scope.item.deliverables[0].steps[0].versions.push({assets:[{url:'aaa'}]})
$scope.item.deliverables[0].steps[0].versions.assets.push({url:'bbb'})
```

Comment: whoa! NSFW tag needed

Comment: if you are still facing trouble let me know so I can help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to access `versions` itself as an array like this:

```
$scope.item.deliverables[0].steps[0].versions = [];
$scope.item.deliverables[0].steps[0].versions.push({assets:[{url:'aaa'}]})
// the item you just pushed in the array is in .versions[0] now
$scope.item.deliverables[0].steps[0].versions[0].assets.push({url:'bbb'})
```

Since you did this:

```
$scope.item.deliverables[0].steps[0].versions = [];
```

`versions` is an array and `assets` as a property to that array is `undefined`. Hence, the error

```
cannot read property push of undefined
```

Comment: You explained the problem, but did not offer code for the actual solution.

Comment: @jfriend00, doesnt the first code snippet offer the solution?

Comment: @jfriend00, would appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: OK, edit offered to clarify as I was confused by the presentation of your answer.